# Defined Path links Breaking

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php I am at a bit of a cross road with defining paths, I found somewhat of a solution on here how ever it works in some breaks in others, I am trying to wrap my head around it.

I'm working on a localhost Zend Server, I found the following

> PATH DEFINE FOR LINKS

```
define ('ROOT_URI', 'http://localhost/mywebsite');
```

and echo it for links and images as so

```
<?php echo ROOT_URI; ?>
```

now this works fine if I am using it for style sheet links and so forth, how ever if the link is sent in an email or redirect it breaks

I did a test account and in the email I put

```
please visit\n<?php echo ROOT_URI; ?>/account/verify.php?email=$email
```

what came back in the email was

```
please visit\n<?php echo ROOT_URI; ?>/account/verify.php?email=you@youremail.com
```

also when redirect it breaks it stays in the folder
like so

```
redirect("<?php echo ROOT_URI; ?>/account/login.php");
```

am I missing something?

I have tried

```
redirect('.ROOT_URI./account/login.php');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *literally* passing `<?php echo ROOT_URI; ?>` as part of a string. You want to concatenate it.

Like so:

```
redirect(ROOT_URI . "/account/login.php");
```

Comment: stah no it is in a php function but what was explained to me and I assume it is wrong now but when ever you use "" you can apply a echo statement..

Comment: Alright, concatenate it like this: `redirect(ROOT_URI . "/account/login.php");`

Comment: Haha, no problem. I updated the answer with the solution and removed the weird assumption I made.

Comment: Thank you so much some one told me as long as I use " " I would be fine

Comment: stah what about this link it wont work only on this one   echo "<li><a href=ROOT_URI.'/account/profile.php?member=$uid'>member Profile</a></li>";

Comment: Change to: `echo '<li><a href= "' . ROOT_URI. '"/account/profile.php?member="' . $uid . '">member Profile</a></li>';` - Are you using syntax highlighting? If you were, you'd see what is being passed literally and what is not. For example: http://i.imgur.com/8lLhE4J.png shows that it's being passed literally (in grey) however $uid is being recognized as a variable.

Comment: stah thank you so much for taking the time to explain it to me.